# How check the various network operators in my area

Tags: android

I am working on app to check the various network operators in my area.

Sofar I've been using the CellInfo and Subscription info of the current network operator,
but it seems that this class only gives me info on network attached to my SIM card.

Any answer that can move me on to get a list of all available network operators are appreaciated.

I have usedTelephony Manager with Connetivity Manager, but not able to find network Operators in my area.

also tried Cellinfo as well as Subscription info.